# SceneKit Render Artifact

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, metal

I am working on a game with SceneKit.  For now it has 4 walls (4 planes). I have set up to play an MP4 on each wall, with a camera object for the player.  Code is below:

```
self.astralroom = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"AstralScene.scnassets/AstralWall.scn"];
NSURL *playervideoURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wall3" ofType:@"mp4"]];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem1 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:playervideoURL];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem2 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:playervideoURL];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem3 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:playervideoURL];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem4 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:playervideoURL];
self.wall1player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem1];
self.wall2player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem2];
self.wall3player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem3];
self.wall4player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem4];

SKVideoNode *wallnode = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithAVPlayer:self.wall1player];
SCNView *scnview = (SCNView*)self.AstralSceneView;
SKScene *wallscene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(640, 480)];
wallscene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
wallnode.position = CGPointMake(wallscene.frame.size.width/2,wallscene.frame.size.height/2);
wallnode.size = wallscene.size;
[wallscene addChild:wallnode];
SCNNode *wallplane1 = [self.astralroom.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"astralwall1" recursively:true];
SCNMaterial *wallmaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
wallmaterial.diffuse.contents = wallscene;
SCNGeometry *g = wallplane1.geometry;
g.materials = @[wallmaterial];

SKVideoNode *wallnode2 = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithAVPlayer:self.wall2player];
scnview = (SCNView*)self.AstralSceneView;
wallscene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(640, 480)];
wallscene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
wallnode2.position = CGPointMake(wallscene.frame.size.width/2,wallscene.frame.size.height/2);
wallnode2.size = wallscene.size;
[wallscene addChild:wallnode2];
SCNNode *wallplane2 = [self.astralroom.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"astralwall2" recursively:true];
wallmaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
wallmaterial.diffuse.contents = wallscene;
g = wallplane2.geometry;
g.materials = @[wallmaterial];

SKVideoNode *wallnode3 = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithAVPlayer:self.wall3player];
scnview = (SCNView*)self.AstralSceneView;
wallscene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(640, 480)];
wallscene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
wallnode3.position = CGPointMake(wallscene.frame.size.width/2,wallscene.frame.size.height/2);
wallnode3.size = wallscene.size;
[wallscene addChild:wallnode3];
SCNNode *wallplane3 = [self.astralroom.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"astralwall3" recursively:true];
wallmaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
wallmaterial.diffuse.contents = wallscene;
g = wallplane3.geometry;
g.materials = @[wallmaterial];

SKVideoNode *wallnode4 = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithAVPlayer:self.wall4player];
scnview = (SCNView*)self.AstralSceneView;
wallscene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(640, 480)];
wallscene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
wallnode4.position = CGPointMake(wallscene.frame.size.width/2,wallscene.frame.size.height/2);
wallnode4.size = wallscene.size;
[wallscene addChild:wallnode4];
SCNNode *wallplane4 = [self.astralroom.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"astralwall4" recursively:true];
wallmaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
wallmaterial.diffuse.contents = wallscene;
g = wallplane4.geometry;
g.materials = @[wallmaterial];



scnview.allowsCameraControl = YES;
scnview.autoenablesDefaultLighting = YES;
scnview.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];


self.camera = [self.astralroom.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"camera" recursively:true];
scnview.scene = self.astralroom;

self.wall1player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.wall1player currentItem]];
[wallnode play];

self.wall2player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.wall2player currentItem]];
[wallnode2 play];

self.wall3player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.wall3player currentItem]];
[wallnode3 play];

self.wall4player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.wall4player currentItem]];
[wallnode4 play];
```

All this plays as expected. The problem is as you scan around the room, I get an empty white space where 2 walls meet.

[image: Image of the problem]

When you are not looking directly at the corner, it disappears.

[image: Image where the problem does not exist]

I am not sure if there is a setting on the camera object or something with the MP4 files.  I have tried extending the walls past the corner, with no effect.  I can put a post in the corner to cover it up, but I would prefer not too.  Is this just a feature of Metal or am I missing something?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Looks like a far clipping plane issue. Try setting the camera's `zFar` property to, say, 1000.0.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!